How to properly format and load data into couch db
Hello CouchDB community.
I am complete beginer to couchdb and I dont realy know what Im doing here
I have downloaded this data sent on my ubuntu machine
wget https://data.cityofchicago.org/api/views/ydr8-5enu/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD -O chicago_data.json
I am trying to format it so I can batch load it into couch db like this
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/chicago_data/_bulk_docs
-H “Content-Type: application/json”
-u admin:examplepassword
–data-binary @/tmp/chicago_data.json
but when I run this command I get this error
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
could anyone help me format this data properly so I can load it into couch
